# Debugging Lambda Connectivity to EC2

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda, aws-ec2

I have a simple Lambda deployed into my VPC that is making a call to an EC2 host in the same VPC (and subnet).  They both share an SG and I've used the Reachability Analyzer (from the Lambda ENI to the EC2 Instance) and it says they can talk.  But when I test the Lambda it sits on the HTTPS call (the call should be very quick) and eventually the Function timesout.

Any other ways to debug the Lambda->EC2 path, if that is even the issue.

Comment: You probably know this already, but just in case, check that the security group rules allow egress to and ingress from the security group to itself. It's not automatic, like a subnet, security groups are a firewall around each network interface. I'd probably work this out through a process of elimination, connecting to different things on different ports.

Answer (score 0):

This may not apply to everyone but my issue was a 3rd party Firewall that was fronting the ALB.  To test this theory I used the direct internal IP address of the server and it worked fine.